# Jquery only fires, upon inspection of the core element and or use of the orientation detection in mobile and tablets.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented a gallery/slideshow into my webpage, seen Here (www.scandalband.co.uk). However I have come accross an issue that I don't know how to correct. My Jq is not too strong yet but I think the problem is related to,

```
$(document).ready.
```

As I mentioned int he title the slider only fires when I inspect the core element affected by the Jq I.e. the slider. Or alternativly use the orentation detection on mobiles and tablets. I can almost solve the problem by using document.onload rather than document.ready. when I use onload, I get the first image in the slideshow but the slider locks up completely.

**I have provided the affected code**

```
<!-- ꜜꜜ slider initilizer ꜜꜜ -->
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        // Slider Swipe function 
        Slider = $('#slider').Swipe({  
            auto: 3000,  
            continuous: false  
        }).data('Swipe');  

    $('.next').on('click', Slider.next);
    $('.prev').on('click', Slider.prev);
    }); 
    </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and lemme know , i joined all these scripts in  `<head>` of your page

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#wrapper').hide().delay(500).fadeIn("slow");

         if (screen.width<800) {        
              window.location="mobile.html";        
          }
        // Slider Swip function 
         Slider = $('#slider').Swipe({  
                auto: 3000,  
                continuous: false
        }).data('Swipe');  

        $('.next').on('click', Slider.next);

        $('.prev').on('click', Slider.prev);
   }); 
 </script>
```

Comment: No luck unfortunatly... :/

Comment: Tried using `$(function()` ... instead of  `$(document).ready(function()` ?

Comment: Yes I have, but using onload is the onlychange that showed a result. Be it a small one at that.

Comment: check if the slider plugin has a `console.log` or some code relating to `console` script somewhere in its js file and comment it out, i had faced a similar problem with a plugin..

Comment: After looking through it and checking with ctrl+f. There is no code relating to console.log. it appears as if it needs to be updated somehow to fire correctly.

Comment: Yes I checked for both, none exist in the plugin.

Comment: Ok, Could be great if you could provide your code in a fiddle?

Comment: Thank you for consolidating that. Added it back into the head section all seems fine still except that bloody slider... :(

Comment: Try loading the urls from fiddle onto your live page and check once ?

Comment: still no luck could it be a conflict from h-slide.js?

Comment: Yes try once with that commented out

Comment: Still no change, is there any way that i could force a slide to move to the next one on load?

Comment: Slider is actually working , your html structure and divs are messing up i guess...try giving `position:absolute;top:200px;` to #slider and check!

Comment: I cant do that, it will pull the slider from the panels. stopping it from sliding in.

Comment: Yes , im just telling you that there is nothing wrong with your javascript code , i saw the slider plugin working after a little introspection :)

Comment: I made some progress this morning in the fact that the slider is working and the images are moving. But they wont update to appear on the screen until the element is inspected or a device is rotated.

Comment: the parent div has a css property of right : -49% which is making it not visible in the page to beyond the page...check it once

Comment: I cant find this property? are you sure it isnt the effect of h-slide?